# Classicthesis adding "cited pages" text before page numbering in reference section

Tags: classicthesis, back-referencing

I'm coming with a specific question. I'm using classicthesis, and I'm requiring the back reference package

```
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
```

It works perfectly, but I wonder whther it could be added the statement"Cited pages" prior the page number cited in the reference section, and including everything within parentheses. For example:

What I have:

> Hart, J. (1967). Memory and the memory-monitoring process. Journal
>   of verbal learning and verbal behavior, 6(5), 685–691. **12, 13**

What I would need:

> Hart, J. (1967). Memory and the memory-monitoring process. Journal
>   of verbal learning and verbal behavior, 6(5), 685–691. **(Cited pages 12, 13.)**

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)] starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` to help the users willing to help reproduce the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option in `classicthesis-config.tex` (line 35) that you have to set to true:

```
\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{true} % true false
```

No need to call `\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}` then.
Take a look at lines 157 to 180 of the same file for more details.

Comment: In its present form, this doesn't answer the question (about format change for the back.references) and it's best suited as a comment to the question.

Comment: Of course it does answer the question, because the formatting of the backreferences has been taken care of in the template. The question is about classicthesis, not backreferences in general. Please familiarize yourself with the classicthesis template before deleting my answers.

Comment: Sorry, but if I, for example,  add the line `\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{true}` to the example code in my answer, and `\input` the file `classicthesis-config`, I receive errors, so the use of your option is not a matter of just adding it to the code and something else has to be done. This could be a part of your answer, so it is self-contained.

Comment: I agree that `classic-config.tex` has the necessary settings (I am not unfamiliar with `classicthesis`), but it would be good for beginners to show them how to use the config file and its options.

Comment: There actually is a manual where all this has been shown - it's in the template itself. Part I, Some kind of manual, Chapter 1, Introduction. Section 1.3 mentions the use of backreferences.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option redefining `\backrefalt` to produce the desired formatting (notice the plural form if the bibliographical item was cited more than once and the singular form for items that were cited just once):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

% this section is just for the example
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblioxxxyyy.bib}
@article{testa,
author={The Author A.},
journal = {Example Journal A.},
pages = {5-10},
title = {{A Title}},
year = {2015}
}
@article{testb,
author={The Author B.},
journal = {Example Journal B.},
pages = {10-20},
title = {{B Title}},
year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents*}
% end of the section that is just for the example
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
\ifcase #1 %
No citations.%
\or
(Cited page #2.)%
\else
(Cited pages #2.)
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\cite{testa}\cite{testb}\newpage\cite{testa}\newpage\cite{testa}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblioxxxyyy}

\end{document}
```

The resulting bibliography:

[image]